# How to include same layout twice programmatically in android?

Tags: java, android, xml

i have trouble to call layout programmatically, i try in xml using include and its work

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:id="@+id/btnTes"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/LL1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/extend">
    </include>

    <include layout="@layout/extend">

    </include>

</LinearLayout>
```

but i want create it programmatically
this is my extend XML :

```
<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />
```

and this is my java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btnTes;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ViewGroup tes = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.LL1);
    btnTes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTes);
    final View extend = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.extend,null);

    btnTes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "KLIk", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            tes.addView(extend);

        }
    });

}
```

}

when i click btnTes
for the first clicked its ok, but when i click it again my program just force close. This is my error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.siwonhansamu.test, PID: 3796
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Thanks

Comment: You cannot add same View in the layout multiple times. Consider using a `RecyclerView` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't add the same view to multiple parents.

You have to do a copy of the view if you want it multiple times. You could do like this :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ViewGroup tes = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.LL1);
    btnTes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTes);

    btnTes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "KLIk", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            final View extend = LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.extend, tes, false);
            tes.addView(extend);

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> when i click btnTes for the first clicked its ok, but when i click it
>   again my program just force close.

that's the expected behavior. A View's instace can have only one parent. When you press the button for the second time `extend` has already a parent (`tes`), and you cannot call `addView` again on that instance. The quick fix is to move

`final View extend = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.extend,null);`

into `onClick`. This way, every time you press on the Button, a new instance is created.